# TexMaker is not detecting spelling errors for texts copied from another source

Tags: texmaker

I am using TexMaker on my Mac. I have been using it for years. But I always realize that when I copy texts from another source (e.g. Word documents), it doesn't check the spelling errors for these specific texts.

Any idea why this is happening, and how to fix this problem. 
FYI: I have a spelling dictionary (en.GB) file already in my Preference.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I am not answering the question but found a workaround to solve my problem. Maybe this helps other people. That is, When I split the copied text into sentences into new lines, the spell-checker detects spelling mistakes. Still, I do expect the TexMaker should automatically detect spelling mistakes directly when I copy the text from other sources.

Comment: You could add your answer to stop inane comments from other "helpful" users. It is very common in some (admittedly not the majority) of editing applications for the spell checker to not be triggered by pasting objects. In some apps as you note it needs some action such as a split to see a marked difference, in others it may need the spell checker to be redirected to start of inserted text. Others may need to be told to parse the whole text. If it is an issue for your workflow it needs to be raised with the developer, however once I know the oddities of each app I tend to live with them.

Comment: Just to elaborate some editors keep track of where the spelling checks got to and are focused on spell checking "on the fly" or exclude certain zones or not work with language neutral input see https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=93850 it happens notoriously in word  https://www.timeatlas.com/word-spell-check-not-working/ however you may want to see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/444349/texmaker-mac-spell-checking-not-working-before-parencite and from the manual **Warning : spell checking starts at the cursor position and not at the beginning of the document.**

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you have found the answer, but I had a similar problem.

I went to Tools > Options > Language Tab > and then checked Use background spell-checking and my spell check came to life within the document.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but there is no menu called 'Options' under Tools menu. Did I miss something? I am using TexMaker 4.5.

Answer (score 0):

Go to `review` and click on the `spell check down arrow`. Make sure `background spell checking` is checked. If you don't see it there click on `settings` and you will find it.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Can you please add one or more screenshots of the menu one has to use to your answer?